# Java: Understanding enum better

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

Please help me to understand this enum class better.

```
public enum TryMe {

    A("A", "Description of A"), 
    B("B", "Description of B");

    private String a;
    private String b;

    private TryMe(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    //Getter and Setter for 'a' and 'b'

}
```

What happens when I include in a Hibernate Entity class? 
Entity class's corresponding database column expects a String with value of 'A' or 'B'. 
How will just String value will be passed?

Comment: Nope, no setters. And you should definitely declare 'a' and 'b' as 'final'!

Comment: You don't technically *need* the `private` keyword in the enum constructor - all enum constructors are implicitly `private` anyway, and it's a compiler error to try and declare them to be anything else. Whether you include it or not is really down to personal preference though, I know some people like to have it there.

Comment: Enum's are also very helpful when used in place of a standard singleton pattern. @see Josh Bloch's "Effective Java" http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any enum is uniquely identifiable by its name. These constant names, in your case, `A` and `B`, are compiled as `static` fields by the Java compiler where each field contains an instance of the enum type. This way, an enum instance is unique throughout the entire application (or more exact, class loader). It is not possible to alter these fields at any point in time, even with reflection.

As a result, enums cannot be serialized by Hibernate and it is not possible to persist state changes in enums (which you should avoid anyways.) They can only be referenced which is what Hibernate does. [Hibernate / JPA stores enums therefore as either](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html):

- By their constant name (`A`, `B`)
- By their ordinal (`0`, `1`)

The problem with the latter approach is that you cannot longer change the order of your constant values without breaking stored values. If you declared `B` before `A`, all your database representations would be switched out. This will most likely break your application which is why the first storage method is recommended.

When a value is loaded from Hibernate, it will return the value of the field named `A` or `B` in the enum class. If your JVM instance did restart in the mean time, any changes to the enum fields are be lost for this reason.

If you think about it, this also makes perfect sense. Any enum state is global and you could not save a different state for for example `A` and expect it to be represented twice in different states once you load two different values from the database. This would break the enum's contract of being unique.

Answer (score 0):

The string value will not be passed, only the name of the member will be passed. 
Since this is a fixed member, you can always grab back to the value via the key or index of the enum and then get the string value

See the [@Enumerated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html) annotation of jpa.